# How to reference user's input in strings.xml (res/value) Android Studio

Tags: android, string, kotlin, input

I was following a Developers.Android [codelab tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-data-binding-basics#3). In the code I learnt you can use `@={}` (dot notation to access the data inside the data class) to reference data, right in the .xml layout file..

Something like this;

```
        <TextView
            ...
            android:text="@={myName.nickname}"
            ...
            />
```

But I want to be able to use the inputed data several in the strings, something like this;

```
    <string name="bio">Hi, @={myName.nickname}.
        I'm Alexia, I love fish.

        The kind that is alive and swims around in an aquarium or river, or a lake, and definitely the ocean.
        Fun fact is that I have several aquariums and also a river.

        I like eating fish, too. Raw fish. Grilled fish. Smoked fish. Poached fish - not so much.
        And sometimes I even go fishing.
        And even less sometimes, I actually catch something.
        Once, when I was camping in Canada, and very hungry, I even caught a large salmon with my hands.

        I\'ll be happy to teach you @={myName.nickname}, how to make your own aquarium.
        But, @={myName.nickname} you should ask someone else about fishing, though, lol.</string>
```

but when I run this it just returns a the `@={myName.nickname}` as @={myName.nickname}, i.e not the data, I'm trying to reference, **So please how do I reference the data in the strings.xml value file.??**

Thank you for your help in Advance...

Here are my files relevant to this, *if you need you anything please let me know*..

data class:

```
package com.example.aboutme

data class MyName(var name: String = "", var nickname: String = "")
```

activity_main.xml;

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="myName"
            type="com.example.aboutme.MyName" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

format the text:

```
binding.nameText = context.getString(R.string.bio, myName.nickname)
```

layout:

```
<variable
    name="nameText"
    type="String" />
...
<TextView
    ...
    android:text="@{nameText}"
    ...
/>
```

string:

```
<string name="bio">Hi, %s, I'm Alexia</string>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I don't get some things though.. Should the I change the previous variable name and type, or create a new one?? And please then what happen to the data class I created??

Comment: @Edwin Your can delete the previous variable. Set the String variable( it is "Hi, a nick name, I'm Alexia" after setting```binding.nameText = context.getString(R.string.bio, myName.nickname)```) to the ```TextView```